# pass the value to code behind onclick of linkButton

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a table which displays the rows on size of the arraylist. I have a link button which displays the id. But i am not able to fetch the id in the behind code. I have tried using commandArgument but i am not able to get the value.

```
<table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;border-  
 collapse:collapse;">
    <thead class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
        <th class="auto-style1">Navigate</th>
        <th class="auto-style1">Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <%ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList price = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList id = new ArrayList();
        myList= (ArrayList)Session["description"];
        price = (ArrayList)Session["price"];
        id = (ArrayList)Session["id"];
        if (Session["description"]!=null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
            {
                LinkButton1.Text = Convert.ToString(id[i]);%>// Here i have set the value of the text. But in the code i am not able to fetch the id which is clicked.

    <tr>
        <td class="auto-style1">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick ="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton></td>
        <td class="auto-style1"><%=myList[i]%></td>
        <td class="auto-style1"><%=price[i]%></td>
    <% }
        }%>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need the id which is being displayed as the text of link button onclick of that particular link button

Comment: Is there any index out of range error ? Have you debugged the code from .aspx page if you getting id from **Session["id"]** ? Your code works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you set CommandArgument but it didn't work. That is normally the way togo.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument="<% id[i] %>" onclick ="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

What I do suspect that is going wrong is that you are applying a loop yourself (which I rarely see) and it renders LinkButton1 every time, but that will result in multiple controls with the same ClientID, since there is nothing else in the controls tree that distinguishes a LinkButton1 to other LinkButton1's.

I would recommend a Repeater for looping + binding. This is a lot easier if you start using objects rather then multiple session variables. Your approach would benefit from using objects too. Use an object "Navigation" with properties Id, Price and Description.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="someRepeater" runat="server">
     <HeaderTemplate>
         <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;">
             <thead class="auto-style1">
                 <tr>
                     <th class="auto-style1">Navigate</th>
                     <th class="auto-style1">Description</th>
                     <th>Price</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
     </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
             <td class="auto-style1">
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick ="LinkButton1_Click" CommandArgument="<%# ((Navigation)Container.DataItem).Id %>" Text="<%# ((Navigation)Container.DataItem).Id %>"></asp:LinkButton></td>
             <td class="auto-style1"><%# ((Navigation)Container.DataItem).Description %></td>
             <td class="auto-style1"><%# ((Navigation)Container.DataItem).Price %></td>
         </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
     </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

In code behind you construct or take List navigations from Session and bind it to the repeater:

```
    someRepeater.DataSource = navigations ?? new List<Navigation>();
    someRepeater.DataBind();
```

Now each LinkButton1 (or whatever WebControl) can be distinguished, since it's in a different repeater-item, so the row id can also be integrated in the ClientID and hence unique ClientID's.

With the repeater approach you can make whatever list with whatever HTML feature yourself. The repeater is like a way of looping in ASP.Net so ASP.Net can process everything.

Comment: How do i retrieve data in the aspx page. I am facing issue at `<td class="auto-style1"><%# ((Navigation)Container.DataItem).Description %></td>`. It says object does not contain a definition for  description.  I have created a list in code behind and appended the values to the repeater.

Comment: A List<Navigation> ? And Navigation is an object with public properties Id, Price and Description? Apparently you are missing Description or it's not public.

Comment: I am facing issue for all the properties.. This is my code                 `public class view_data
    {
        public int id;
        public String description;
        public int price;
    }                                                                                             List<view_data> viewDataList = new List<view_data>(); viewDataList.Add(new view_data {id=Convert.ToInt16(reader["id"]),description=Convert.ToString(reader["item_description"]),price=Convert.ToInt16(reader["price"])});      Repeater1.DataSource =viewDataList;
             Repeater1.DataBind();`

Comment: and in aspx  `<td class="auto-style1"><%# ((view_data)Container.DataItem).Description %></td>`. Here i am getting error for all the properties

Comment: You wrote your property description, not Description. So when u get the property you should call the name you gave it, so with a lower d: ((view_data)Container.DataItem).description

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That worked for me.. However i am getting another error while adding the values into the list `viewDataList.Add(new view_data {id=Convert.ToInt16(reader["id"]),description=Convert.ToString(reader["item_description"]),price=Convert.ToInt16(reader["price"])});`.. The error is input string was not in correct format

Comment: That's the issue if you set properties while initializing. Initialize and then set each property in separate statements, so you can debug it and it throws an error on the exact value it can't parse. But I bet it's price, which is probably not an int, but you are parsing to an int. Just sort that issue and remember; you learned 2 things here: use objects and use a repeater for looping to build whatever html you need.